# Access container and list content with HTTP

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

How can i access a container and list the blobs with http in Windows azure ?

Thanks,

Comment: I created a container with public access permissions and i tried to acess the container throught the navigatore like http://exemple.azureblobstorage.com/containerName/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `myblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list`.

Take a look at [this reference article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135734.aspx) for more information on the List Blobs API.